# Saving/Storing the name of a selected option from an optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, flask

So currently I have a drop down menu that is populated with a json file with each option looking like such (there are many more sets in the actual file) :

`JSON`

```
{
  "thing": {
    "Selected thing": [
      {
        "name"   : "thing 1",
        "value"  : 1.0,
        "purpose": "thing 1"
      }, 
    ]           
  }
}
```

They are being populated into the below HTML select with a script:

`HTML`

```
<tr>
  <td><strong>Choose a Thing</strong></td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <select name="thing" class="form-control" id="thing" value="{{ thing  }}">
        <option class ="placeholder">{{ thing }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

`JavaScript`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var menu = document.getElementById('thing')
  $.getJSON("{{ url_for('static', filename='things.json') }}", function (data) {
    $.each(data.things, function (optgroup, options) {
      var next_optgroup = document.createElement('OPTGROUP')
      next_optgroup.setAttribute("label", optgroup)
      menu.appendChild(next_optgroup)
      $.each(options, function (index) {
        next_option = document.createElement('OPTION')
        next_option.setAttribute("value", options[index].value)
        next_option.setAttribute("name", options[index].name)
        next_option.innerHTML = options[index].name
        next_optgroup.appendChild(next_option)
      });
    });
  });
})
```

So currently, once the selected option is chosen and a submit button is pressed, the value (1) is passed to Flask and stored and rendered to the select options value via {{ thing }}.

I need it to function as it does, but I also need to be able to store the name that is associated with the selected option which I feel I may need to use javascript or some hidden inputs (definitely place another input on my HTML form) to do this, though my knowledge of javascript is minimal.

In other words, how would I be able to store and upon a refresh of the page, keep the selected options name (thing 1) displayed on the HTML page?

Comment: Attach a [changeListener](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to the select and save the changes to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage ([https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp](http://Web%20Storage%20-%20Local%20Storage)) described in the link can be used to store data in the User's browser on their local machine. This means that if they visit the page from a different computer, they will not be able to access that stored data. If you need to persist this information and access it from different machines/browsers, then you will have to implement a Database on a live web server and request this information when the user hits the page.

Local Storage is simple to use. Here is an example of how to set the a variable for the User's selected thing:

```
// Using jQuery
$('#thing').on('change', function() {
// Save the Value in local storage
localStorage.setItem('userThing', $('#thing').val());

});
```

To load the value from storage after the page is ready AND you have built and populated the 'thing' select form element:

```
// Get the 'userThing' from local storage and set the select element with id 'thing'
$('#thing').val(localStorage.getItem('userThing');
```

These task is vary common for Javascript developers. Frameworks such as Google's AngularJS and Facebook's React have been built to simplify these tasks (That is they are very simple to do after you have learned the framework...which will take a little while to feel comfortable using but well worth the effort if you intend to build large projects using javascript). They rely heavily on the MVC paradigm which is strongly recommend in developing Web Applications.

Comment: Thanks Matt I appreciate the response, though it's not the value of the select option I'm after. I'm able to store the selected value using Flask and have it reappear on the form using Jinga2, though I'm unsure as to how to get the name "thing 1", whose name does not become the selects name after submitting. I feel I may need to do something with the index of the dropdown list and then loop through the json file to find the name attributed to that index, though I'm not positive.